# how do I allocate memory for some of the structure elements

Tags: memory-management, malloc, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I want to allocate memory for some elements of a structure, which are pointers to other small structs.How do I allocate and de-allocate memory in best way?

Ex:

```
 typedef struct _SOME_STRUCT {
    PDATATYPE1   PDatatype1;
    PDATATYPE2   PDatatype2;
    PDATATYPE3   PDatatype3;

    .......

    PDATATYPE12   PDatatype12;
} SOME_STRUCT, *PSOME_STRUCT;
```

I want to allocate memory for PDatatype1,3,4,6,7,9,11.Can I allocate memory with single malloc? or what is the best way to allocate memory for only these elements and how to free the whole memory allocated?

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a trick that allows a single `malloc`, but that also has to weighed against doing a more standard multiple `malloc` approach.

**If** [and *only* if], once the `DatatypeN` elements of `SOME_STRUCT` are allocated, they do *not* need to be reallocated in any way, nor does *any* other code do a `free` on any of them, you can do the following [the assumption that `PDATATYPEn` points to `DATATYPEn`]:

```
PSOME_STRUCT
alloc_some_struct(void)
{
    size_t siz;
    void *vptr;
    PSOME_STRUCT sptr;

    // NOTE: this optimizes down to a single assignment
    siz = 0;
    siz += sizeof(DATATYPE1);
    siz += sizeof(DATATYPE2);
    siz += sizeof(DATATYPE3);
    ...
    siz += sizeof(DATATYPE12);

    sptr = malloc(sizeof(SOME_STRUCT) + siz);

    vptr = sptr;
    vptr += sizeof(SOME_STRUCT);

    sptr->Pdatatype1 = vptr;
    // either initialize the struct pointed to by sptr->Pdatatype1 here or
    // caller should do it -- likewise for the others ...
    vptr += sizeof(DATATYPE1);

    sptr->Pdatatype2 = vptr;
    vptr += sizeof(DATATYPE2);

    sptr->Pdatatype3 = vptr;
    vptr += sizeof(DATATYPE3);

    ...

    sptr->Pdatatype12 = vptr;
    vptr += sizeof(DATATYPE12);

    return sptr;
}
```

Then, the when you're done, just do `free(sptr)`.

The `sizeof` above *should* be sufficient to provide proper alignment for the sub-structs. If not, you'll have to replace them with a macro (e.g. `SIZEOF`) that provides the necessary alignment. (e.g.) for 8 byte alignment, something like:

```
#define SIZEOF(_siz) (((_siz) + 7) & ~0x07)
```

*Note:* While it is possible to do all this, and it is more common for things like variable length string structs like:

```
struct mystring {
    int my_strlen;
    char my_strbuf[0];
};

struct mystring {
    int my_strlen;
    char *my_strbuf;
};
```

It is debatable whether it's worth the [potential] fragility (i.e. somebody forgets and does the `realloc/free` on the individual elements). The cleaner way would be to embed the actual structs rather than the pointers to them if the single `malloc` is a high priority for you.

Otherwise, just do the the [more] standard way and do the 12 individual `malloc` calls and, later, the 12 `free` calls.

Still, it *is* a viable technique, particularly on small memory constrained systems.

Here is the [more] usual way involving per-element allocations:

```
PSOME_STRUCT
alloc_some_struct(void)
{
    void *vptr;
    PSOME_STRUCT sptr;

    sptr = malloc(sizeof(SOME_STRUCT));

    // either initialize the struct pointed to by sptr->Pdatatype1 here or
    // caller should do it -- likewise for the others ...
    sptr->Pdatatype1 = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE1));
    sptr->Pdatatype2 = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE2));
    sptr->Pdatatype3 = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE3));
    ...
    sptr->Pdatatype12 = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE12));

    return sptr;
}

void
free_some_struct(PSOME_STRUCT sptr)
{

    free(sptr->Pdatatype1);
    free(sptr->Pdatatype2);
    free(sptr->Pdatatype3);
    ...
    free(sptr->Pdatatype12);

    free(sptr);
}
```

Comment: I can do this but the problem with Klocwork is it will insist on checking the return value for each malloc call ! ( I am talking about the standard way you mentioned )

Comment: I'd reask Ates' question about why pointers _must_ be used. IMO, unless you need to realloc individual elements using DATATYPEn instead of PDATATYPEn seems better. Either method I posted should pass muster as they're both legit. However, I'll bet klocwork will complain about the trick. However, there is a "subpool" allocation method [that I didn't post] that would reduce the number of mallocs. If you can explain your requirements/constraints a bit more, I might be able to adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's just that I have to use predefined structure somebody defined earlier in my project, and it is been used in various other places so I cant change the structure itself.

Comment: If the struct is already defined, I presume there are already alloc/free functions [like my "std" version]--better to use those. On the big **if** I mentioned, does anybody do "out-of-band" realloc/free on the individual elements? That is, once you create the outer "SOME" struct, do they leave the data ptr values untouched [e.g. nobody else does sptr->pdata1 = realloc(...), but they are allowed to do sptr->pdata1->xxx = 32]? If _yes_, the subpool method can work. Otherwise, fallback to std [using pre-existing fncs, if possible]. Sounds like you're bound to this, so no worries either way.

Answer (score 0):

If your structure contains the others structures as elements instead of pointers, you can allocate memory for the combined structure in one shot:

```
typedef struct _SOME_STRUCT {
    DATATYPE1   Datatype1;
    DATATYPE2   Datatype2;
    DATATYPE3   Datatype3;

    .......

    DATATYPE12   Datatype12;
} SOME_STRUCT, *PSOME_STRUCT;

PSOME_STRUCT p = (PSOME_STRUCT)malloc(sizeof(SOME_STRUCT));

// Or without malloc:
PSOME_STRUCT p = new SOME_STRUCT();
```

Comment: If it had other structs instead of their pointers I can directly use them through `SOME_STRUCT` without allocating memory, can't I?

Comment: Yes, if you define a variable as: `SOME_STRUCT s;`

Comment: Can you add the condition that you need to use pointers in the original question? In that case, the most straightforward way is to malloc for the substructures individually.